# Integrating Instagram API With Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instagram

I'm very new to rails and have very little experience with programming in general. I was given the project of creating a simple rails app that is able to check a users Instagram when given their User ID and Password. My question in general is how do I approach this? Where do I start and essentially how do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you should never ask for the user's password for an external service (no sane user will give it to you). Instead use omniauth (omniauth-instagram, specifically) to get an access_token and then simply use the Instagram ruby gem (https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem) to get their timeline.